# Converting the form of solution of a linear system of differential equations.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

If I have a system of homogeneous linear differential equations given by,
$$
\frac{d}{dt}Y = AY
$$
The solution is of the form, $$ Y(t) = \sum c_i v_i e^{\lambda_i t}$$
where $v_i$ are the eigenvectors and $\lambda_i$ are the corresponding eigenvalues of $A$.

But suppose I want to convert this form into the other one i.e,
$$ Y(t) = e^{At}C = Pe^{\Lambda t}P^{-1}C $$
without finding the inverse of the eigenvector matrix $P$ explicitly. How would I achieve this?

I tried to write $C$ as $\sum c_i v_i$ to get,
$$ \sum c_iv_ie^{\lambda_it}=\sum c_iPe^{\Lambda t}P^{-1}v_i$$
but I don't know how to proceed further. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.